# How to get sharing persons info from Picasa photo?

Tags: java, picasa

I want to get some information about photo from picasaweb.google.com
I use Google Java Client Library.
I receive photo information in com.google.gdata.data.photos.PhotoEntry class, but I don't see methods for retrieving sharing persons list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this functions is not realized.

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=292&q=share&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary